# Intermediate inequalities; is there a way to know if you're getting a "bad deal"?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, reference-request, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let's say I want to prove a contest-style inequality $f(a, b, c) + g(a, b, c) \ge h(a, b, c)$ in some $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$. Suppose I want to make the RHS simpler by applying the AM-GM inequality, so that now it remains to prove $2\sqrt {f(a, b, c) g(a, b, c)} \ge h(a, b, c)$. However, this new inequality may or may not be true. So my questions are:

1) Is it known which inequalities are "better than others"? For example, when you solve an inequality do you think "Let me try to avoid using QM-AM, Am-HM is better"

2) If there are no general rules for question 1), is there a way for me to tell if I'm getting a "bad deal" by using some inequality?

3) Does the answer to $1)$ depend on the internal structure of the expressions you're applying the inequalities to? For example, is it possible that applying AM-GM to $a^2+2b+c$ and $b^2+2a+c$ gives a very bad inequality, but applying something like $\dfrac {ab}{c}$ and $\dfrac {bc}{a}$ gives a very good inequality?

If you have a book recomendation that deals with the topic I would appreciate it as well.

Comment: Do you think that this has an answer?

Comment: @scentofthetrees I think at least 3) has an answer

Comment: The answer would either be "yes" or a treatise in inequalitites. This is the type of questions that should be closed in this site.

Comment: @scentofthetrees I have added the reference-request tag and edited the question. Also, I think there is a chance that the answer is "Yes, polynomials tend to be good for AM-GM but rational functions not su much", or "around singularities C-S is not so good", etc.

Comment: I honestly think the best answer to this line of questioning is just to do hundreds of problems, and then you'll get a feel for which inequalities are better than others and which give bad deals. I mostly think this is the best answer, since there is no easy mathematical answer.

Comment: @mathworker21 Ok thanks for the advice!

Comment: @mathworker21 Is there a way to analyze a specific problem to see if you got a bad deal or not? Like by trying to graph or something? I can see that from hundreds problems, one might get an intuition for which inequality is good to use when. But I'm still not sure how I would know which gives a "bad deal", if I can't even tell for a specific problem if I got a bad deal.

Comment: I think it's easy to tell for a specific problem. For example, if after you apply AM-GM, the inequality you seek is no longer true, then AM-GM was a bad deal. If you can apply AM-GM and still prove the inequality you seek, then it might be a good deal (if it's easier to conclude the inequality you seek than if you didn't use AM-GM, then I'd say it was a good deal).

Comment: @mathworker21 But isn’t the problem that you don’t even know if the problem is a good inequality or not? Like if the original inequality was a good deal, and you used AM GM to prove it, then you know AM GM was a good deal. But how can you know that the original inequality was a good deal to begin with?

Comment: You just explained how you can know AM-GM is a good deal. Apply that reasoning/explanation to the original inequality (in the setting of proving another inequality).

Comment: This is an art, not a science. If you have access to a computer, you can always try to numerically check the strengthened inequalities (or bash them with the $\left(a,a+x,a+x+y\right)$ method when they are symmetric).

Comment: I think a best way to learn inequalities it's just to read the forum  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6_inequalities In any case you need to be ready to solve very many problems. If so, good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I agree with the comments that this is an art rather than a science, there are patterns, and one important one (at least for me) came from [The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~ehudf/courses/Ineq09/The%20Cauchy-Schwarz%20Master%20Class%20.pdf) (J. Michael Steele).

You typically get a "good deal" from inequalities when you're working in a region where the inequality is sharp.

As an (obvious) example, say you're working with the approximation $e^x \geq 1 + x$. Obviously this approximation is terrible most of the time (proof by picture below)

[image: e^x >= 1 + x]

But notice this inequality is *sharp*, (i.e. $e^x = 1+x$) when $x = 0$. This tells us (basically by continuity) that this equality is a *good deal* when $x \approx 0$. The graph above shows this.

This is a good example, because we know from calculus *exactly* how good a deal this approximation is, and why it becomes a better and better deal as $x \to 0$. Thankfully, this same heuristic can be used in many important inequalities.

---

Since you mention the AM-GM inequality, let's ask *when is AM-GM sharp?*

One can show (and indeed you should) that 
$(a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n)^{1/n} = \frac{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n}{n}$ iff the $a_i$ are all the same.

This gives us a clue as to when we should use the AM-GM inequality: we get a good deal whenever the $a_i$ are approximately equal! Let's try to use this to prove something fun: Carleman's Inequality.

$$\sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty (a_1 a_2 \cdots a_k)^{1/k} \leq e \sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty a_k$$

The left side of this is crying out for the AM-GM inequality! You might suspect that hitting the left side with AM-GM will give rise to something with the desired sum, plus some extra $\frac{1}{n}$ terms which we can massage into $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$ to get our factor of $e$. Unfortunately...

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n (a_1 a_2 \cdots a_k)^{1/k} 
\leq 
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=1}^k a_j
=
\sum_{j=1}^n a_j \sum_{k=j}^n \frac{1}{k}
$$

This sum will diverge in the limit, and it seems we're out of luck. The problem, as you may have guessed from the fact that I'm using this as an example, is that we are applying the AM-GM inequality where it is *weak*. If we can reframe the problem in a way that guarantees the $a_k$ are all roughly the same, then we can get a better bargain when using it.

Let's fix this problem with the least possible effort - we'll introduce a new sequence $c_k$ such that $c_1 a_1 \approx c_2 a_2 \approx c_3 a_3 \approx \cdots$.
If we repeat our calculation with these new fudge factors, we can figure out later what exactly they should be to make the inequality work out.

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty (a_1 a_2 \cdots a_k)^{1/k}
&=
\sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty 
\frac{(a_1 c_1 a_2 c_2 \cdots a_k c_k)^{1/k}}{(c_1 c_2 \cdots c_k)^{1/k}}\\
&\leq
\sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty 
\frac{a_1c_1 + a_2c_2 + \cdots + a_k c_k}{k(c_1 c_2 \cdots c_k)^{1/k}}\\
&=
\sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty a_k c_k 
\sum \limits_{j=k}^\infty \frac{1}{j(c_1 c_2 \cdots c_j)^{1/j}}
\end{align*}
$$

Ok, at some point we have to actually do work, and this is where that happens. We want to make 
$$s_k = c_k \sum \limits_{j=k}^\infty \frac{1}{j(c_1 c_2 \cdots c_j)^{1/j}}$$
a convergent sequence. Preferably one which is bounded above by $e$, so that we can recover the desired inequality.
We again take the easiest path to making this sum converge - let's *force* it to telescope. Recall

$$\sum \limits_{j=k}^\infty \frac{1}{j(j+1)} 
= 
\sum \limits_{j=k}^\infty \frac{1}{j} - \frac{1}{j+1} 
= 
\frac{1}{k}
$$

Our sequence $c_k$ is still undefined. If we define it so that
$(c_1 c_2 \cdots c_j)^{1/j} = j+1$, that forces

$$
s_k 
= 
c_k \sum \limits_{j=k}^\infty \frac{1}{j(c_1 c_2 \cdots c_j)^{1/j}}
=
c_k \sum \limits_{j=k}^\infty \frac{1}{j(j+1)} = \frac{c_k}{k}
$$

But what *is* $c_j$? Notice $(c_1 c_2 \cdots c_{j-1}) = j^{j-1}$ and 
$(c_1 c_2 \cdots c_j) = (j+1)^j$. Thus

$$c_j = \frac{(j+1)^j}{j^{j-1}} = j \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{j} \right )^j$$

Now we see the light at the end of the tunnel!

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty (a_1 a_2 \cdots a_k)^{1/k}
&\leq
\sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty a_k s_k\\
&=
\sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty a_k \frac{c_k}{k}\\
&=
\sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty a_k \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{k} \right )^k\\
&\leq
e \sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty a_k
\end{align*}
$$

---

This example was fairly long, but hopefully shows how we can ensure we get a "good deal" from our inequalities just by ensuring we use them where they are sharp.
This example was (almost verbatim) taken from the book I mentioned at the top of the post, The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class. It is absolutely worth reading, and changed the way that I (a dyed-in-the-wool algebraist) approach analysis and inequalities. It is packed full of tricks and tips for getting the most out of your inequalities, and does a good job explaining how and when to apply them at their full power. I found it useful, and I hope others do too!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Wow thank you so much that is awesome!! Would you happen to know where in the book this comes from? I have skimmed at AM GM chapter at some point in the past and I don't remember seeing this.

Comment: Page 27! Though the entire book is worth reading. Also, if this answered your question, please mark it as such so others know where to spend their time.

Comment: Thanks again for the beautiful answer; I am just leaving it open for some more time so that other people may present different ideas if they have any.

Comment: In the end, the series doesn't actually fulfill $c_1 a_1 \approx c_2 a_2 \approx c_3 a_3 \approx \cdots$, does it?

Comment: Somewhat embarrassingly, that thought genuinely never crossed my mind when reading this proof... Some quick computation leads me to agree with you, and I'm not sure what to make of it. If nothing else, the idea of using a fudge factor, in the interest of trying to make the sequence closer to constant (as well as the idea that we should use inequalities around where they are sharp) is one that I stand by... I admit, though, it's confusing that in this example the distance between terms actually gets worse